# Share some before_filters between controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, multiple-inheritance

I have two parent controllers, one for an API, one for normal html pages.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    ...
end

class ApiController < ActionController::Metal
    include AbstractController::Callbacks
    ...
end
```

I want to share some `before_filter` on both controllers. I tried something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    include MyFilters
end

class ApiController < ActionController::Metal
    include MyFilters
end

module MyFilters
    before_filter :filter1
    before_filter :filter2

    def filter1
    end

    def filter2
    end
    ...
end
```

And also this:

```
module MyFilters
    def self.included(klass)
        klass.before_filter :filter1
        klass.before_filter :filter2
    end

    def filter1
    end

    def filter2
    end
    ...
end
```

But in both cases I receive:

```
undefined method `before_filter' for MyFilters:Module
```

What is the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) for that:

```
# app/controllers/concerns/my_filters.rb
module MyFilters
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :filter1
    before_filter :filter2
  end

  def filter1
  end

  def filter1
  end
end
```

Use them through a standard `include` in your controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include MyFilters
end

class ApiController < ActionController::Metal
  include MyFilters
end
```